# Python installation of setup tools gives syntax error

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip, easy-install

I get this error when I type in the terminal `python ez_setup.py`

```
Admins-MBP:PlugIns christoph$ python ez_setup.py
File "ez_setup.py", line 1
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 01:25:11) 
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What happened so far?

1. I downloaded the recommend Tcl/tk (ActiveTcl 8.5) and installed it.
2. I downloaded the .dmg of the Python 3.3 from the python site.
3. I installed xCode (for the GCC compiler - don't know weather that is of interest).
4. I went to this site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and copied the code, opened my python 3.3 IDLE, pasted it into it and saved a file named `ez_setup.py`.
5. I opened my terminal, changed with `cd` to the folder where my `ez_setup.py` file is located.
6. I tried to install this file with `python ez_setup.py` which prompts me the erromessage above.

The reason why I want to install `easy_install` is to install `pip` in the following. It seems easier to install `pip` with easy install since I cannot install `pip` with `python get-pip.py` neither. I want to set that up properly.

I am working with Python 3.3 on a freshly installed version of OS X 10.10.1

*edit:
Solved as in read the accepted answer. For installing it into the python3.3 folder (since I am using 3.3) change to the directory where the `ez_setup.py` file is located and type into the terminal:
`python3.3 ez_setup.py` (or replace the `3.3` with your python version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went wrong here:

> I went to this site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and copied the code, opened my python 3.3 IDLE, pasted it into it and saved a file named ez_setup.py.

You saved a *Python shell session*, not the script itself. The shell session is the output produced by code you run in the shell, and the first lines of the shell include the Python version.

Use the New File option (CMD-N) and paste the code in there, then save *that*.

Comment: Ill try that. Hang on.

Comment: Works now, but there is another error message. Something with `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-1534.pth'`
Could we take that to the chat?

Comment: @Stophface: you are more than welcome to join us in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: @Stophface: The solution is to use `sudo` however. `sudo python ez_setup.py`, and enter your password. You'll then execute the command as administrator, which does have permission to write in `/Library/Python/...`.